Why was Jill only infected after being hit by Nemesis at the clocktower?
In the first and third Resident Evil games, when Jill goes about her business in Spencer Mansion and Racoon City, she gets bitten all the time and is just fine until she gets attacked by Nemesis at the clock tower, and only at the clock tower does she get infected.
If she was suspectable to T, why didn't it affect her until then, and if she's only suspectable to Nemesis's T, why didn't it affect her until then?

Which of these games are you asking about?

literally any version of RE and RE3, doesn't change shit, Jill was still in the manson and Jill Still gets infected at the clock tower
